# How to override inline CSS without using !important or javascript?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to override inline CSS without using `!important` and without using JavaScript?

For example:

```
<div style="background-color: red;"></div>
```

I was wondering if it can be overridden without:

```
div {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious. What's your scenario?

Comment: I'm using kendoui which injects a lot of it's own inline css. I don't like using important and I don't like writing javascript for things which should be handled in CSS. So I have the options to do these but would like it if there were a cleaner way...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, inline style takes precedence, you can override it only with `!important`.

Comment: I thought so too, tried all kinds of CSS specificity

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the !important clause is specifically created as *the* solution for this. It would be impractical for CSS to implement different degrees of priority, apart from the now-used 
`style block < inline < !important`
 priority.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div[style] {
  background: blue !important;
}
```