# How to change td background-color of td on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a table in my project. Each `td` of this table has initial `background-color:#fafafa`.

Here is my code:

```
<style>
    .uTbId tr td:hover {
        background-color: #0000CD;
        color: green;
    }
</style>
<table class="uTbId" border="1" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;margin-top:30px" bordercolor="lightgray">
    <tr>
        <td style="position:absolute;width:100px;background-color:#fafafa">
            <input type="checkbox" id='Tom' />Tom</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to change td backgroud-color from #fafafa to "#0000CD" when mouse over it, and I tried:

```
<style>
.uTbId tr td:hover{background-color:#0000CD;color:green;}
</style>
```

But it works fail. The `td` backgroud-color is still #fafafa when mouse over the td.

And then I tried another way and I found that if `td` without initial backgroud-color, it works OK. Like:

```
<td style="position:absolute;width:100px"><input type="checkbox" id='Tom'/>Tom</td> // works OK
```

I am confused, it seems nothing is wrong. I can not delete the td initial background-color in my project.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You can override it using `!important` in the stylesheet but I'd argue it's not ideal to have part of the styling defined inline and part of it in the stylesheet (for the same element). If both were in the stylesheet you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML email - TD hover to change back background-color not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238580/html-email-td-hover-to-change-back-background-color-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS Specificity is preventing that, since style tag is more specific than given css style. Answers here suggest to `!important`, but I urge you to not use it, unless it is absolutely necessary. Just give your `td` a class and you will be done

```
<style>
  .uTbId td.check {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #fafafa
  }

  .uTbId td.check:hover {
        background-color: #0000CD;
        color: green;
  }

</style>
<table class="uTbId" border="1" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;margin-top:30px" bordercolor="lightgray">
    <tr>
        <td class="check">
            <input type="checkbox" id='Tom' />Tom</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the default `background-color` in the css itself, otherwise inline styles can only be [overriden by !important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234137/how-to-override-inline-css-without-using-important-or-javascript).

```
.uTbId tr td {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: green;
}
```

**Demo**

```css
.uTbId tr td {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: green;
}

.uTbId tr td:hover {
  background-color: #0000CD;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="uTbId" border="1" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;margin-top:30px" bordercolor="lightgray">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px;"><input type="checkbox" id='Tom' />Tom</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you can check where **on mouse hover on any td will give you, your given background-color.**

```html
<table class="uTbId" border="1" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;margin-top:30px" bordercolor="lightgray">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px;"><input type="checkbox" id='Tom' />Tom</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
  table.uTbId tr>td:hover{
     background-color:#0000CD;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add !important to the background-color on hover.

```
background-color:#0000CD !important
```

Since you added the style as inline, the white background you gave has taken precedence and hence you get this error. Adding !important fixes this...

**Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpQybJ